# coldfusion IIS web.config for URL ReWrites getting 404 error

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, coldfusion, web-config

I have two separate websites on my server:
X:\Inetpub\wwwroot\MySite1\ and X:\Inetpub\wwwroot\MySite2.

I'm trying to set up some URL Rewrites, so I'm starting simple.  I created a web.config file in X:\Inetpub\wwwroot\MySite1\web.config with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Contact" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^contact$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/16_Contact.cfm" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When someone enters the url "MySite1.com/contact", I want the browser to take them straight to "MySite1.com/16_Contact.cfm".  But when I try it in a browser, I get a 404 error.  I'm using an ancient version of Coldfusion (MX7), if that matters.  Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have the Rewrite module installed in IIS?  It's not there out of the box, I'm pretty sure you have to deploy it.  Your config looks normal.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the Rewrite module, but I'm hand-coding the web.config file.  Are there dependent files I may be missing?

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?  From this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/25169995/1246574 looks like some folks have trouble in IIS 8 and above, and there are a few solutions.  I've used the module, but in IIS 7 and it works for me just fine.  I don't think its your config, I think it's more likely that the module isn't installed properly.

Comment: IIS version 7.5.7.  So I can't just create a web.config file and save it on the server?  There has to be some kind of direction from IIS?

Comment: Check the detailed error information. It shows you how the requested page is resolved. See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakkimk/2007/05/25/iis7-how-to-enable-the-detailed-error-messages-for-the-website-while-browsed-from-for-the-client-browsers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a while since I have used CF7, but I remember running into this issue, and it had something to do with the order in which CF and the rewrite module were added to the site in IIS.

First make sure your Coldfusion installation has the most recent patches, then try using the Web Server Configuration Tool that comes with Coldfusion to remove and re-add the Coldfusion modules/settings to your IIS site.

Comment: We are in the process of upgrading to CF10.  I may get our IT department to come and re-setup my IIS manager once that is complete and see if that does the trick.